# Execute a command under the cursor in Vim

Tags: vim

1. How can I execute a command in Vim, under the cursor? On the (word) under the cursor?

We know that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> is used to open a man page under the cursor. I want to execute the command instead of opening the man page.

Or:

2. How can I take the current word under the cursor in Vim?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How can I take the current word under the cursor in VIM?

```
echo expand("<cword>")
```

or

```
let l:WordValue = expand("<cword>")
```

How can I execute the command under the cursor? I am not exactly sure what kind
of commands you're refering to, but since you mentioned man pages, I'd assume
that you want to execute unix and or cmd commands. If this is the case you'll
want something like

```
fu ExecuteCommand()
   let l:Command = expand("<cword>")
   execute "!" . l:Command
endfu
```

Alternatively, you might want to change the value of `keywordprg`:

```
:set keywordprg=!
```

Answer (score 23):

Another tip: If you want to put the word currently under the cursor into the command-line mode, use the sequence <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: C-r, C-w in sequence is meant here

Comment: And you need to already be in command mode (`:`). So, for a command to run in the shell and you are in normal mode, cursor over the word, type `:!`, then C-r, then C-w.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a command typed in a buffer and the cursor is on the line, to execute it do this:
first yank what you want to execute, `Y` or `yy` will copy the whole line, then in the command line you can type `@"` and hit Enter

or do this combination `<C-R>` `"` to paste literally

or put this mapping in .vimrc

```
" execute line under the cursor
nnoremap <leader>el yy:@"<CR>
```

`@"` stands for the default `"` register, any text that you delete (with d, c, s or x) or yank will be placed there